# Read the content of a file and display with line numbers on the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

I am trying to write code to read a Ruby script entered by the user and stored it in a temp file, then pass that temp file to `jruby -c temp_file` to do syntax validation.

If any errors are found, I have to show the errors, along with the script entered by the user with line numbers.

How would I do this?

Comment: I was trying something like this
File.open("newfile,txt","w") do |out|
  File.open("myfile.txt").each_with_index do |line, index|
    out << "#{index}: #{line}"
  end
end

Comment: Please edit your question and append the code sample so it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a syntax error you see the failing line number:

`blah.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '.'`

So just split your script on newline (`\n`) and thats your error line (1 index based of course).

Comment: Good one, but I got some jquery plugin to do the same and the plugin name is jquerylinedtextarea (http://alan.blog-city.com/jquerylinedtextarea.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, you can use `jruby-parser` (install `gem install jruby-parser`) with JRuby to find line numbers where errors occur:

```
require 'jruby-parser'

# Read script file into a String
script = File.open('hello.rb', 'r').read

begin
  JRubyParser.parse(script)
rescue Exception => e
  # Display line number
  puts e.position.start_line
  # Display error message
  puts e.message
end
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried the above method given by you, but I am getting the following error

NoMethodError (undefined method `position' for #<NativeException:0x14aedaa>):

Comment: @DeanM Do you have an example of a parsed script causing that error so we can reproduce?

Comment: I tries the following code and it worked for me, now the only problem I am getting is it is giving me error one by one lets say there are 3 errors in the script , but you wil only get the first one and if you solve first then only you will get the other ones. I want some way to show all the syntax errors at once>

Comment: Here is the code , I tried
script = File.open("#{Rails.root}/#{self.name}.rb", "r").read
   begin
    JRubyParser.parse(script)
   rescue org.jrubyparser.lexer.SyntaxException => e
    self.errors[:base] << "#{e.cause.message} on line number <span class='error_line_number'>#{e.cause.position.start_line}</span> ---#{e.cause.get_cause}--#{e.cause.methods.inspect}".html_safe
   end